# UITableView forced to be UITableViewStyleGrouped but still UITableViewStylePlain sometimes

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, initwithstyle

I have a `UITableViewController` and i use custom init methods like

```
-(id)initWithCustomStuff{
   self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
   if (self) {
       // Custom stuff happening

   }
return self;
}
```

And as you see, I forced the `TableView` with `[super initWithStyle:]` method to always be `UITableViewStyleGrouped`.

Mostly i got my grouped table, but sometimes with some devices like an iPhone 5 with iOS7 and an iPad mini with 6.1.2 i got a `UITableViewStylePlain`.

Note: A week ago i rebuilded this view, because before i used a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` inside and other stuff, now i make it to a `UITableViewController` and also i removed the .xib file and all the subviews i don't really needed.

Maybe it somehow referenced to the .xib? I removed it from the project and also deleted it and deleted the outdated version from the devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting the class and making a new one without a .xib file, then coping anything back to the new header and source file solved the problem.
Maybe it was some random `Xcode` but caused by using multiply versions of `Xcode` in the same time. I still don't know what was the real matter.